# How do I license a font I created to sell

Tags: licensing

I just recently created a font using the Fontself plugin for Illustrator and I want to figure out how to protect my font with a license and distribute it.
The problem is that everything I've found online is for the user and how to purchase a font license, not license a font **FOR** purchase/distribution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a license agreement that satisfies your business objectives.  Or,
2. Find an open-source or other existing license that satisfies your objectives.  Or,
3. Pay a lawyer to write a license that satisfies your objectives.

Your objectives might include terms and conditions on when, where, or how your font can be used by a licensee.